# AssertJ JUnitSoftAssertions and Guava assertions

Tags: java, guava, junit4, assertj

I'm addicted to the AssertJ JUnit rule [`JUnitSoftAssertions`](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core/api/org/assertj/core/api/JUnitSoftAssertions.html). It is really conveniente, you just add it as a test class field

```
@Rule
public JUnitSoftAssertions softy = new JUnitSoftAssertions();
```

and you chain several `assertThat` on it.

Now, I added the dependency for [Guava assertions from AssertJ](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-guava.html), but looks to me that there is no rule or no way to register the new assertions in the JUnit rule. Hence I must use ugly static imports.

Am I wrong? If so, please explain how to use them in a JUnit rule (without implementing it by myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no soft assertions support in assertj-guava at the moment but adding it is not too difficult, it only requires a class like:

```
/**
 * A single entry point for all soft assertions, AssertJ standard assertions and MyProject custom assertions.
 */
// extending make all standard AssertJ assertions available
public class GuavaJUnitSoftAssertions extends JUnitSoftAssertions {

  public <K, V> MultimapAssert<K, V> assertThat(final Multimap<K, V> actual) {
    return proxy(MultimapAssert.class, Multimap.class, actual);
  }

  // add the other guava assertThat methods 
  // ... 
}
```

Happy to get a contribution for that (I'm a bit busy at the moment).

Hope it helps

Comment: Hey thanks. Yes I realized that things were in that way at the end. I ended up with an implementation [like that one](https://github.com/ozimov/cirneco/blob/master/assertj/assertj-guava/src/main/java/it/ozimov/cirneco/assertj/JUnitGuavaEnhancedSoftAssertions.java).

Comment: @Joel, I'd love a little hint on how to do this for `OptionalAssert<T>`!

Comment: Try adding a method like the one for multimap:

    `public <T> OptionalAssert<T> assertThat(final Optional<T> actual) {
        return proxy(OptionalAssert.class, Optional.class, actual);
    }`